# Can I use the Twitter gem to pull Twitter .user data from multiple Twitter names at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

Ok. I've got a Ruby on Rails application and have successfully gotten authentication (thanks to other responses here). I can get it to tweet, read from the timeline, pull followers of the authenticated user, etc.

However, now what I'm looking to do is pull the follower lists of the authenticated user, determine which (if any) of those accounts is verified or not and then display the verified accounts. I can pull the nickname of each follower, however, it seems like I have to do each call individually (.user(ID#1) then .user(ID#2) then etc.) which results in me hitting the rate limit cap.

Therefore, what I'm looking for is a way to pass multiple IDs and return the user information for each ID in one call (or at least fewer than a 1 ID: 1 API call). I feel like this has to be possible (in fac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, just do:

```
Twitter.users(id1, id2, id3)
```

Docs: http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/twitter/Twitter/Client#users-instance_method

Comment: Thanks. I had that same page open and literally just wasn't reading that it was allowed.